# VB.Net Custom Mask for Date/Time AM/PM

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, datetime, maskedtextbox

Here's what I'm trying to do.... I have a field in my application where I am to capture datetime something like this 11/02/2016 12:19 PM (example). I have a field in SQL Server with `datatype = smallDatetime`. It gets saved like this `2016-11-02 12:19:00`. In my app I set the CUSTOM **mask** to 00/00/0000 90:00 am. Now what I'm trying to do is populate this saved date into my masked textbox but it does not look proper. Is there a way for me to format is somehow so when I try to populate the field in my application it looks properly? This is what I've been trying to figure out...

```
If Not IsDBNull(Dt("SavedOn")) Then
  txtSavedOn.Text = Format(Dt("SavedOn"), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt"))
End If
```

Wha thappens is the PM/AM part gets displayed incorrectly and it only shows the M and a number instead of p/a

[image]

Comment: For dataType i saved it previously as datetime, then changed it to smalldatetime - I'm not sure if I should just save it as nvarchar

Comment: Never store dates as string if you want them to act like dates.  Why not just use the datetimepicker?

Comment: @plutonix no datetimepicker per spec sheet :/

Comment: Note that without a validating type, there is no guarantee that the result will be a valid DateTime.  99/07/0123  matches the date mask

Comment: I'm running a validate function to check the date I was just having a hard time trying to display it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your mask to

> 00/00/0000 90:00 aa

Also your date format

```
txtSavedOn.Text = Format(Dt("SavedOn"), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt"))
```

(note the capital MM for month, opposed to lower mm for minute)

Comment: Should I still keep the datatype in sql server as smalldatetime, and aslo - should I format it the same when saving it to sql server? Thanks!

Comment: If you must format it before storing in SQL, I suggest using `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm` to avoid confusion. Using a model from Entity Framework or Linq to SQL allows you to pass a DateTime which is easier but I don't have that level of detail. DateTime vs. SmallDateTime? One is more accurate and supports a wider range of dates than the other, so it depends on your application. See http://sqlcoach.blogspot.com/2007/08/sql-server-storing-time-coming-soon.html

Comment: @verdoline - this seems to work (your answer) everything looks good! Okay I'll keep the formatting that way - in this case I dont care about too much accuracy as long as its to a minute (smalldatetime will work in that case). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Just use this code

```
 txtSavedOn.Text =  Dt("SavedOn").tostring("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")
```