# VB.Net Validating Date

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, validation, date

Came across a small issue - I have a function where I pass DATE as String. This Date then gets passed as parameter to a stored procedure where I validate it, and it returns a value (0,1) whether it's valid or not. Here's what's going on code wise...

```vb
If CheckDateSP(mskAppointment.Text) Then
   'Great now lets use this date
else
   msgbox "Invalid date, re-enter please"
End if
```

Passing it into a function.....

```vb
Public Function CheckDateSP(ByVal CheckThisDate As String) As Boolean
    'Setting Connection strings and all the good stuff 
    'here's where it gives me an error
     Dim vDate As DateTime = CheckThisDate <----HERE is the error

End Function
```

Now here's the interesting part - I only get an error if I input a date like...

> 13/13/2016

Everything works perfectly fine if I enter dates such as these...

> 12/12/2017 , 10/10/2014

or any other date as long as month is less than 13

The error I get is....

> ERROR converting from String '13/13/2016' to Type Date is not Valid.

Comment: 13/13 ?????????

Comment: Yes, well i want to make sure this is a valid date, you know how users are entering god only knows what.

Comment: `Dim vDate As DateTime = CheckThisDate` if CheckThisDate  is passed in as string you cant just assign it like that - convert or TryParse it  (that wont even compile under Option Strict)

Comment: Then use DateTime.TryParse to avoid exceptions

Comment: @Steve maybe it's a lunar calendar

Comment: make sure that you are using the right date format, for example if the format was mdy (mm/dd/yyyy) then your date will be invalid and it gives you error.

Comment: you can change the date format in sql using: "set dateformat dmy" statement for dd/MM/yyyy format or  "set dateformat mdy"  for MM/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: @Bobski I'm sorry, but [we did this yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389211/vb-net-custom-mask-for-date-time-am-pm), didn't we? You insist on passing around dates as strings contrary to how we suggested you store dates as dates. That is the problem.

Comment: @Verdolino - I stored it as datetime/smalldatetime - never saving it as string. I'm only using a function where the date is passed as a string. All dates work fine - i've tested it with at least half a dozen. that was until i entered a completely bogus date as 13/13/2016. users enter all crazy dates. I'd rather used dtp but not allowed.

Comment: But it can only be invalid when it is a string.  Use `DateTime.TryParse` on the textbox text when you get the values from the form.  Once it is a `DateTeime` it cant be invalid

Comment: @Bobski everytime you assign a string to a datetime variable you put the correctness of your code in the hands of the VB compiler and in the will of the user international settings. You can only hope that the  environment in which you code runs allows to make sense of the string like a date. You shouldn't write a so weak code. There are many ways to be sure that you have a valid date. I recommend to study how to use _DateTime.TryParse_

Comment: Add `Option Strict On` to the top of your code file or go into your project's settings and turn it on.  If you're concerned about users entering bad dates, why let them?  Give them a UI control specifically for entering dates that will prevent them from entering a bad one, i. e. a `DateTimePicker`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```vb
Dim input As String = "13/13/2016"

Dim dt As DateTime
If DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "MM/dd/yyyy", New Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, dt) Then
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The string '{0}' parsed to '{1:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}'", input, dt))
Else
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Couldn't parse '{0}'", input))
End If
```

The call to `TryParseExact` returns true when it's in the correct format, and false when it's not. Note, the format provided to `TryParseExact` is in the form month/day/year and I used `Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")` because I'm in the US.

Comment: Thanks this great.

Comment: It's too bad you can't use a DateTimePicker instead of the MaskedTextBox. It returns a DateTime so you wouldn't need to bother with this.